# How to change the backgroundPosition of a div with a onClick event from another element

Tags: php, javascript, background-position

How do I put this together? I'm working on this website that requires that every time that a item from the menu is clicked the background-position of two specific DIVs change and keep the selection.

Here is my attempt:

First I create a variable "p" to save on the url/address the selected page, so for example, if you are in about us you will probably see something like this on the address bar:

website.com/index.php?p=aboutus

On the menu, on the button about us I did this with a call to the function changeBG onClick:

```
<a href="?p=aboutus" onclick="changeBG()">About Us</a>
```

I figured I need javascript to do the trick and here is where I'm stock.

This is the script that goes in the header:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <?
// Set "p" value to HOME if previously empty. 
if ($_GET['p']=='') $_GET['p']='home';
    ?>  
function changeBg(pvalue) {
if (pvalue == '') {pvalue = '<?=$_GET['p'];?>';
    }
    if  (pvalue=='aboutus'){
    document.getElementById('this_is_the_first_to_be_changed').style.backgroundPosition=0 20px;
            document.getElementById('this_is_the_other_to_be_changed').style.backgroundPosition=0 80px;

            if  (pvalue=='contactus'){
            document.getElementById('this_is_the_first_to_be_changed').style.backgroundPosition=0 10px;
                   document.getElementById('this_is_the_other_to_be_changed').style.backgroundPosition=0 100px;
    }

            }
  </script>
```

This is what goes on the body:

```
<div id="left_menu">
<a href="?p=aboutus" onclick="changeBG()">About Us</a>
<a href="?p=contact" onclick="changeBG()">Contact Us</a>
</div>
<div id="this_is_the_first_to_be_changed">
</div>
<div id="this_is_the_other_to_be_changed">
</div>
```

Can anyone spot why this doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work, but I'd strongly urge you not to mix your business logic and your display logic the way you're doing it. Just because PHP makes it possible, doesn't mean it's a good idea. Very quickly you wind up with totally unreadable code (as in your example above). Trying to figure out what parts are PHP and what parts are Javascript is an absolute nightmare (since they are such similar looking languages), so you should do everything possible to keep them as separate as you can.

Comment: I agree with you but what you see is just part of the iceberg. You can take a pick at the whole project here:

www.daterraweb.com/projects/brazilpax/site/v1/

What I'm actually trying to do is to move those blue arrows by the left and top menu respectively up and down, and sideways, so they will match with the full yellow arrow.  If you have a better idea, please

Answer (score 0):

Try it using quotes:
style.backgroundPosition="0 20px";

UPDATED

Also, what about this line: 
pvalue = '';

you are setting pvalue='=aboutus'

UPDATED

The script element is incorrect:

```
<script type="java/text">
```

right is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

In addition use firebug or chrome to see the JS generated in the page.

Comment: No. Quotes did not do the trick, but I was wondering if using it, wouldn't turn the values into a string?

Comment: Yes... that the ideia. Fill up the pvalue with the value of the p. P is a variable that the value changes when you click an item on the menu. I did that using href="?p=aboutus" . Anyway. pvalue is receiving the right content. THe problem is in the conditional. If you want to see the real project please visit, www.daterraweb.com/projects/brazilpax/site/v1/

Comment: Oh.. i see what are you are saying. Yes, Its redundant, but in the end pvalue is still getting the right value though.

Comment: Yeah... I see that, but it wasn't it either. :(